# How to load multiple extensions in "headful" chrome with puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I found a code that successfully loads an extension when launching puppeteer chromium but I was unable to get it to work with several extensions.

As per Paul Browne's post, it should work like this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/659#issuecomment-409589805

```
var options = {
  headless: false,
  args: [
    '--disable-extensions-except=/path/to/ext1/, /path/to/ext2/, /path/to/ext3/'
  ]
}
```

It works well when I only type 1 path, but the comma separated list of path doesn't work. Browser still opens but it loads only the 1st extension in the order how they are listed inside the flag. The `--load-extension` was indeed not needed to get extension to load.

Anyone figured out a solution for multiple extension?

Comment: Try removing the spaces or enclose the paths in doublequotes like `'--foo="a","b","c"'`

Comment: @wOxxOm Awesome, simply removing spaces worked, no additional quotes. I tried many things but not this:)

Answer (score 11):

You can load multiple extensions this way:

```js
const ext1 = 'path to ext1';
const ext2 = 'path to ext2';
const ext3 = 'path to ext3';
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: [`--disable-extensions-except=${ext1},${ext2},${ext3}`]
});
```

Make sure that there are no spaces in your comma-separated list of extensions, so make sure it's

```
${ext1},${ext2},${ext3}
```

and **not**

```
${ext1}, ${ext2}, ${ext3}
```